# Laravel 5.1 PHPunit error when testing urls with method call or visit

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test my controllers and routes on laravel 5.1 with phpunit.

I got this error:

.PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PagoCheque' not found

This is because on my views I instanciate the Object PagoCheque.

I have two questions:

1. Can I test the controllers o routes without calling the views?
2. If I can't how can I instanciate all the Objects that the view needs to instanciate to work.

My code is:

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{

use WithoutMiddleware; 

/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function testExample()
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}

public function testListadoMenu(){

        $this->visit('/listPagoCheques')
        ->see('Listado');

}
public function testUrl(){

        $response = $this->call('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());

}
}
```

Hope that anyone can give directions.

Thanks in advance.

Updated:

Class Controller:

```
public function listPagoCheques()
{

    $input = Request::all();


return view('cheques.listPagoCheques')->with('cheques',$cheques)
    ->with('nro_recibo',$nro_recibo);

}
```

View :

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<? 
use App\domain\PagoCheque;
?>

  <!--div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="page-header"></h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
 <!--/div-->
 <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>Pago Cheques</li>
    <li class="active">Listado Pago Cursos</li>
</ul>


<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="cheque">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Nro Recibo</th>                   
               <th>Nro Disposici&oacute;n Fija Fecha</th>                   
               <th>Nro Disposici&oacute;n Pago</th>
               <th>Nro. Memo</th>
               <th>Monto Solicitado</th>
               <th>Actividad</th> 
               <th>Subgrupo</th>
               <th>Beneficiario</th> 
               <th>Disponible</th> 
               <th>Importe Cheque</th>
               <th>Entregado</th>
               <th></th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach ($cheques as $cheque)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $cheque->nro_recibo }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cheque->nro_disp_otorga }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cheque->nro_disp_aprueba }} </td>
            <td> {{ $pago_cheque::getNroMemoById($cheque->nro_memo_id) }} </td>
            <td> $ {{ $cheque->importe}} </td>
            <td> {{ $pago_cheque::getNombreCursoById($cheque->curso_id)}}</td>
            <td> {{ $pago_cheque::getNombreSubgrupoById($cheque->curso_id)}}</td>
            <td> {{ $pago_cheque::getNombreDocenteById($cheque->docente_id)}}</td>
            <td> {{ $pago_cheque::getDisponibleChequeById($cheque->disponible_id) }}</td>
            <td> $  {{ $cheque->importe_cheque}} </td>
            <td> {{ $pago_cheque::getEntregadoChequeById($cheque->entregado_por_id) }}</td>
            <td> <a href="{!! URL::action('ChequesController@editCursoPagoCheque',$cheque->pago_cheque_id); !!}">Ver</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem can't be with instantiation, because the associated Controller would do that well. You probably are referring to the ClassName in a wrong way. May be you are missing the namespaces etc.

Comment: In the userTest class I added these namespaces but im getting the same error: 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use App\domain\PagoCheque;

Comment: Would you like to share more code? `PagoCheque` the associated view & controller as well..may be

Comment: The controller call the view like this:
public function listPagoCheques()
 {

 return view('cheques.listPagoCheques');
  
 }

And the view had this namespaces to create the objects:

@extends('app')

@section('content')

<? 
use App\domain\Utils;
use App\domain\Actuacion;
use App\domain\PagoCheque;
?>
<div> ... then html code that is not the case.

Comment: I have to add the custom namespaces in other file in phpunit?

Comment: what is the code of `PagoCheque`? In the meantime, I believe you are not following the standard rules of MVC development. You don't use `use` inside views. In case you need certain class method, you should prefer the `@inject` blade directive

Comment: I'm using static methods which I have in this PagoCheque Class.

This line is the error.

 <td> <?php echo e(PagoCheque::getNroMemoById($cheque->nro_memo_id)); ?> </td>

Comment: So, I have to inject the object and not use `use` in the view. Will try that. I didn't know that is not a good practice :S

Comment: update ur question and share the code of all the things I mentioned above. Including that of the pagocheque class

Comment: I did that and it seems to work. 
added @inject('pago_cheque', 'App\Domain\PagoCheque') inside the view.

Now I have another error :(.  Target [App\Domain\User] is not instantiable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122855/discussion-between-user1252306-and-huzaib-shafi).